# How do I make it so each button I press in my calculator app combines the numbers together?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

I am working on making a calculator app as my first 'real' coding project. I understand that there is a large quantity of tutorials on the web on how to make one, but I would rather figure out how to break down the problem into smaller steps myself.

That being said, I have run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out on my own. Each button that I press swaps out the previous value for the value attached to that button. I am struggling to see how to program it so each button pressed combines the two values together. (e.g "1" and "2" = "12")

Any ideas?

Thank you!

https://codepen.io/tphelps5/pen/GRgBMMZ?editors=1010

JavaScript

```
let reset = document.getElementById("reset"),
    output = document.getElementById("output"),
    calcButtons = document.getElementById("calc_buttons");

calcButtons.addEventListener("click", printNum, false);

function printNum(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    let clickedItem = e.target.value;
    output.innerHTML = clickedItem;
  }

  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

HTML

```
<HTML> 
  <h1> My First JavaScript Calculator </h2>
  <div id="calculator">

  <div id="calc_buttons">
    <span id="output"></span>

    <button class="operate" id="reset" value=" ">C</button>

    <button class="num" id="seven" value="7">7</button>
    <button class="num" id="eight" value="8">8</button>
    <button class="num" id="nine" value="9">9</button>

    <button class="operate" id="divide" value="/">/</button>


    <button class="num" id="four" value="4">4</button>
    <button class="num" id="five" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="num" id="six" value="6">6</button>

    <button class="operate" id="multiply" value="*">*</button>

    <button class="num" id="one" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="num" id="two" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="num" id="three" value="3">3</button>

    <button class="operate" id="minus" value="-">-</button>


    <button class="num" id="zero" value="0">0</button>

   <button class="operate" id="decimal" value=".">.</button>
   <button class="operate" id="equals" value="=">=</button>


   <button class="operate" id="plus" value="+">+</button>

</div>



</HTML>
```

Comment: `output.innerHTML = clickedItem` should be `output.innerHTML += clickedItem`

Answer (score 0):

### How to concatenate numbers from user input

Keeping track of user input to concatenate numbers is straightforward.

You'll need to do 2 things:

1. Keep track of numbers entered, break it off and store it somewhere when an operator is entered
2. Keep track of all numbers and operators entered

```js
let arr = []; // contains your list of numbers and operators in the order they were entered
let str = ""; // the current number string
function printNum(e) {
    ...// your own code logic
    if (e.target.value === "+" || e.target.value === "-" || ...) { // all the math operators here OR replace with regex matching
        // for OP: Add logic to handle accidentally pressing >1 operator in succession
        arr.push(str);
        str = "";
        arr.push(e.target.value)
    } else {
        str += e.target.value;
    }
}
```

You will end up with an array that looks like this:

```js
 arr = ["12","+","15","*", ...]
```

Calculating the value of the array could be quite tricky, and will be a good exercise.

### A more complete answer

My primary objective was to provide you a clear and easy solution without adding too much to your code. Before the answer, please take note of the risks:

> Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval(). See Never use eval()!, below.

#### Answer:

A simple (and lazy way) is to maintain a string that keeps track of the user input  and do the actual calculations with [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

*This doesn't account for incorrect user entries. Eg. 1+2++3+5+*

Basic usage:

```js
let str = "1+3+5";
let ans = eval(str); // ans is now "6"
```

From here, you see that a string with correctly formed mathematical operators will `eval` to the final result of the equation.

If you are comfortable with this approach, you can simply do:

```js
let str = ""
function printNum(e) {
    ...// your own code logic
    str += e.target.value;
}
```

I omitted the full working example in case you wanted to work on the rest of the problem yourself. If you'd like it for reference, see [this pen](https://codepen.io/Polared/pen/LYEXaba).

Comment: Not a bad answer, maybe not even a base use-case for eval. Though, probably not a good idea to even make a beginning programmer aware of eval. Seems like something that, learned early, would be used often :/

Comment: That's true, which is why the warning came before the answer :P

Comment: * btw, I meant to say "not even a bad use-case" :)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
output.innerHTML = clickedItem;
```

replaces the content of `outer` with the clickedItem.  Try

```
output.innerHTML += clickedItem;
```

which appends it to the content instead.

(Yes, + appends strings and adds numbers.  This will only occasionally cause terribly confusing bugs.)